# Getting NoReverseMatch error in Django

Tags: python, django

The strangest thing is that I just copied the following code from working part of the program, just switched names, all basics the same.

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /profile/1/
Reverse for 'follow_user_add' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/follow/']
```

ulrs.py:

```
url(r'^profile/', include('basics.urls')),
```

basics/urls.py:

```
url(r'^follow/', 'basics.views.add_user_follower', name='follow_user_add'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='users_detail'),

url(r'^', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
```

views.py:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'basics/profile_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_object'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["member_list"] = Member.objects.filter(user=self.object)
        return context

def add_user_follower(request, pk ):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = TempForm(request.POST or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
                ...
                return HttpResponseRedirect(followed_user.get_url()) 

    else:
        form = TempForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'basics/profile_detail.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

and template:

```
<form action="{% url 'follow_user_add' user_object.id %}"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="follow" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out your error, You gave the url like this,

```
url(r'^follow/', 'basics.views.add_user_follower', name='follow_user_add'),
```

But in template like this,

```
action="{% url 'follow_user_add' user_object.id %}"
```

So the above url matches like this way `/profile/follow/1/`. But your url `/profile/follow/`.

And in views like this,

```
def add_user_follower(request, pk ):
```

And you got this error,

```
Reverse for 'follow_user_add' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/follow/']
```

My solution you have matching the url with pk, But you didn't have that pattren. So you need to put this way,

```
url(r'^follow/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'basics.views.add_user_follower', name='follow_user_add'),
```

Note: you basically missed the `(?P<pk>\d+)` pattren. Hope this helps you.

Update: change the urls this way,

```
url(r'^follow/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'basics.views.add_user_follower', name='follow_user_add'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='users_detail'),

url(r'^$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
```

Comment: Thanks for ur comment! I changed url, still got error: `Reverse for 'follow_user_add' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/follow/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

Comment: @Harkonnen I updated my answer. Please review it once.

Comment: @Harkonnen I found `\\d+` in `['profile/follow/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`. you need to replace with `\d+`. This `\` character.

Comment: Hmm.. I still got error with **['profile/follow/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']** and double \\ , but in my urls its **r'^follow/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',** . Maybe problem here? **action="{% url "follow_user_add" user_object.id %}"**

Comment: ok last try `action="{% url follow_user_add user_object.id %}"`